# What could cause "Error evaluating Jacobian of equality constraints at user provided starting point" in pyomo.dae

Tags: pyomo

My model is giving this error and I have no idea what's causing it. I can post more detailed info including code if necessary.

This results in "ValueError: Cannot load a SolverResults object with bad status: error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means that you have not initialized your variables and the default initialization of 0 cannot be evaluated in one or more constraint expression. Maybe you're dividing by an uninitialized variable (division by zero) or raising to a negative exponent or taking the log.